# How To to find out the creation time of the filesystem in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to know the creation time for the filesystem in linux .

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not Unix tech support and administration. Questions like this belong on unix.SE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tune2fs tool to get creation time:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
```

In result one of the lines is:

```
Filesystem created:       Mon Apr  4 15:07:44 2016
Last mount time:          Mon Dec 12 14:48:51 2016
Last write time:          Mon Dec 12 14:48:50 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

This command works on ext2 -ext 4 filesystem. The command is not supported on XFS filesystem. Refer the below link: [man tune2fs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs)